# Reactive Extensions Wait For Queue Empty

Tags: .net, asynchronous, system.reactive

I have the following async queue processing routing.

```
      var commandQueue = new BlockingCollection<MyCommand>();
      commandQueue
            .GetConsumingEnumerable()
            .ToObservable(new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskPoolScheduler(5))
            .Subscribe(c =>
                           {
                               try
                               {
                                   ProcessCommand(c);
                               }
                               catch (Exception ex)
                               {
                                   Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
                               }
                           }
            );
```

In one specific scenario (when I'm about to get some data), I need to make sure that my commandQueue is empty before going out and getting the data. This operation is expected to happen synchronously. Basically, I want to do something like

```
  public void GetData()
  {
     commandQueue.WaitForEmpty(); 

     // could potentially be expressed: 
     // while (commandQueue.Count > 0) Thread.Sleep(10);

     return GoGetTheData()
  }
```

I realize that in an ideal scenario, all callers will "GetData" async...but sometimes it's necessary that it happen in a synchronous manner...and so I need to wait for the command queue to be empty to ensure the consistency and up-to-date-ness of my data.

I know how I can do this pretty easily with a ManualResetEvent...but I'd like to know if there's an easy way with System.Reactive/TPL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more difficult question than it seems at first. You want `BlockingCollection` (and the underlying `ConcurrentQueue`) for producer-consumer job semantics. But you also want to be able to observe what's happening with these collections, including waiting for the 'empty' signal.

Best bet is to take a look at `JobQueue` and `ParallelJobQueue` from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/2817c6e5-e5a4-4aac-91c1-97ba7de88ff7

Which includes an observable for `WhenQueueEmpty` and can control the number of simultaneously running jobs and queued jobs (jobs being synonymous in this case with your command concept).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use this?

```
    var dataObservable = Observable.Start(() =>
    {
        commandQueue.WaitForEmpty(); 
        return GoGetTheData();
    });
```

Comment: The issue is that there is no such method as WaitForEmpty

Comment: @JeffN825 - What is `BlockCollection` then? Is it something you've defined?

Comment: sorry, not sure how that got truncated in my example. it's BlockingCollection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: @JeffN825 - I'm not an expert on `BlockingCollection` but I would imagine that there are a number of built-in mechanisms for determining when the queue is empty. Just choose one for the `WaitForEmpty` method. Does that help?

Comment: Sort of. I can easily check if it's empty, but what's the most effective way of waiting? Something more effective than Thread.Sleep preferably.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your requirements are to

- Fetch data asynchronously
- Process this data in parallel (max of 5 degrees of parallelism)
- Repeat the process

If these are your requirements and you are not forced to use the BlockingCollection i.e. it is not an existing API, then I think you can solve this quite easily with Rx alone.

```
var dataRequestScheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
var subscription = GetTheData()
    .Repeat()
    .SubscribeOn(dataRequestScheduler)
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)//new LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskPoolScheduler(5)
    .Subscribe(c =>
           {
               try
               {
                   ProcessCommand(c);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
               }
           }
        );
```

Where GetTheData method returns an IObservable

You could potentially leverage Observable.Start and Merge(5) to get your max 5 threads without the need for a custom scheduler.